# Use CocoaPods Module in React Native Custom UI Component

Tags: objective-c, xcode, google-maps, cocoapods, react-native

I'm building a React Native UI component which will make use of the Google Maps iOS SDK to render maps in a React app. This is being built as a static Cocoa Touch Framework so that I can use it in different projects.

So far this framework doesn't do much, I'm just trying to get it to compile before I try and do anything useful with it. I have a `Podfile` which loads in the Google Maps SDK and I've run the `pod install` command:

```
# Uncomment this line to define a global platform for your project
platform :ios, '8.1'
# Uncomment this line if you're using Swift
# use_frameworks!

target 'GoogleMapView' do
    source 'https://github.com/CocoaPods/Specs.git'
    pod 'GoogleMaps'
end
```

I have `GoogleMapView.h` and `GoogleMapView.m` files which will do the heavy lifting in this module. For now they don't really do much:

```
@import GoogleMaps;

@interface GoogleMapView: GMSMapView

@end
```

--

```
#import "GoogleMapView.h"

@implementation GoogleMapView {
    GMSMapView *mapView_;
}

- (void)viewDidLoad {
    // Create a GMSCameraPosition that tells the map to display the
    // coordinate -33.86,151.20 at zoom level 6.
    GMSCameraPosition *camera = [GMSCameraPosition cameraWithLatitude:-33.86
                                                            longitude:151.20
                                                                 zoom:6];
    mapView_ = [GMSMapView mapWithFrame:CGRectZero camera:camera];
    mapView_.myLocationEnabled = YES;
    self.view = mapView_;

    // Creates a marker in the center of the map.
    GMSMarker *marker = [[GMSMarker alloc] init];
    marker.position = CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(-33.86, 151.20);
    marker.title = @"Sydney";
    marker.snippet = @"Australia";
    marker.map = mapView_;
}

@end
```

Then I have `GoogleMapViewManager.h` and `GoogleMapViewManager.m` files which provide the bridge to React Native. Again, these don't do much right now!:

```
#import "RCTViewManager.h"

@interface GoogleMapViewManager : RCTViewManager

@end
```

--

```
#import "GoogleMapView.h"
#import "GoogleMapViewManager.h"

@implementation GoogleMapViewManager

RCT_EXPORT_MODULE()

- (UIView *)view
{
    GoogleMapView *map = [[GoogleMapView alloc] init];

    return map;
}

@end
```

I've added this library to my React Native XCode project like so - there are some red files listed (I'm not too sure what they mean?):

[image: Xcode File Tree]

I've also added the product from my static library to the `Link Binary With Libraries` list in the `Build Phases` section of the main React project:

[image: Build Phases]

However, when I try to compile the project, I get some errors which are causing the build to fail like so:

[image: Build Failure]

I'm certain that I've done something wrong when importing the Google Maps SDK using CocoaPods. I wasn't able to follow the docs and use the `.xcworkspace` file when importing my static library into the React app which is possibly what's wrong, but I can't figure out how to get it to run!

*Update:*

I can get the code to compile if I include the map project using the `.xcworkspace` file, but then I'm not able to access the binaries or include them in any build phases which isn't useful:

[image: Use .xcworspace file instead]

Does anyone know how I could make use of the Google Maps iOS SDK like this in a React Native app?

Comment: Not sure how to use CocoaPods in a library project, but you could include those Google Maps-related classes directly in your original React project (if you don't plan on sharing the library)

Comment: That's what I've had to revert to doing - this causes a big problem if you need to update the React version since the `# react-native upgrade` command makes a mess of the XCode project.

Comment: I think the cleanest way to do it would be to install react-native via CocoaPods and add your dependency as another Pod.

Comment: @edcs : Where you able to resolve this issue? I need some help on this?  From My main project, i need to add this native module and  native module intern uses some framework which i am connecting thru cocoapod. 

So for module i tried with static library and added that with my main project . But these pod dependancy will be installed in Xcode workspace, not in Xcode project. So how can i add this in my main project .

Comment: @EXC_BAD_ACCESS - I never resolved it and I am no longer part of this project. The workaround I used was to write a shell script which automatically downloaded the SDK upon NPM install (https://github.com/Pod-Point-Open-Source/react-native-maps/blob/master/sdk.sh). Think the answer below might help too but I never got a chance to try it out.

Comment: @edcs Thanks for your input

Answer (score 2):

In the case that you have a React Native App Project, let's call it `MyApp.xcodeproj`, and you are including a library project, `GoogleMapView.xcodeproj`, you won't be able to use CocoaPods in GoogleMapView just by dragging it into `MyApp.xcodeproj` as you have done in this example.

If you want to use CocoaPods to pull in the `GoogleMaps` Pod, you must pull in your `GoogleMapView` project ALSO using CocoaPods.

Like so:

```
# MyApp/Podfile

pod 'GoogleMapView', :path => 'Libraries/GoogleMapView'
```

But before you do that, you'll need to make sure that the `GoogleMapView` project / private CocoaPod is correctly configured.

First, the Podfile:

```
# MyApp/Libraries/GoogleMapView/Podfile

pod 'GoogleMaps'
```

Then, the Podspec. This file is what marks the project as a CocoaPods library.

You can generate this with `pod spec create GoogleMapView`.

Here's what yours needs to look like:

```
# MyApp/Libraries/GoogleMapView/GoogleMapView.podspec

    Pod::Spec.new do |s|

      s.name         = "GoogleMapView"
      s.version      = "0.0.1"
      s.summary      = "A short description of GoogleMapView."

      s.description  = <<-DESC
                       DESC

      s.homepage     = "http://EXAMPLE/GoogleMapView"
      s.license      = "MIT (example)"


      s.author             = { "David Young-Chan Kay" => "davidykay@gmail.com" }

      s.source       = { :git => "http://EXAMPLE/GoogleMapView.git", :tag => "0.0.1" }

      s.source_files  = "Classes", "Classes/**/*.{h,m}"
      s.exclude_files = "Classes/Exclude"

      # This is the key line. You must add it by hand.
      s.dependency 'GoogleMaps'

    end
```

Once these three files are in place, you will be able to re-use your `GoogleMapView` using CocoaPods!

You can even upload it to the central CocoaPods repository for sharing with others.

Hope this helps. Let me know if you need clarification.

Comment: This looks great - thanks for the answer. I'll have a go at implementing it all when I've got a spare minute or two :)

Comment: Good luck! Let me know how it goes. :)

Comment: May be the anwser is not right.  Because in the GoogleMapView we will use   react-native.But in the pod development, there is no react-native.

Comment: Thanks to this post, I managed to create my own react-native module using GoogleMaps (and extracted it into a npm package).
https://github.com/surialabs/react-native-geo-fencing